# Antd-moment-webpack-plugin affects other dayjs instances in node_modules

Tags: webpack, momentjs, antd, dayjs

I'm trying to replace the dayjs default of antd v5 to use moment. Ant Design gave us the webpack plugin for it `@ant-design/moment-webpack-plugin`, but, it replaces the dayjs instances in other packages in the node_modules.

When I run the application it gives a compile error that looks like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ant-design/pro-utils/es/conversionMomentValue/index.js 5:0-55
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear' in '~\client\node_modules\@ant-design\pro-utils\es\conversionMomentValue'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 3:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/weekday' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 4:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/localeData' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 5:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 6:0-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/weekYear' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 7:0-57
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/dayjs.js 8:0-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat' in '~\client\node_modules\rc-picker\es\generate'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 43:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/isBetween' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 44:0-55
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrAfter' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 45:0-57
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 46:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/localeData' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 47:0-59
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/localizedFormat' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 48:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/minMax' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-big-calendar/dist/react-big-calendar.esm.js 49:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/utc' in '~\client\node_modules\react-big-calendar\dist'
```